# Is it okay to use SQLite to store translations instead of XML resources like strings.xml

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite, android-studio

I wanted to find a way to give a user to chose language of app instead of changing it from device settings. App is meant for people who use rare language, that isn't supported on most of devices. I was searching for answers of "How to change app language programmatically?", but my head ached. So i just want to use SQLite not only for storing all app datas, but also to store translations of captions, labels, etc that are usually stored in "strings.xml". So is it okay? Is anyone gonna think that it's a bad practice?

Comment: This will be a headache as the system do this automatically every time you call `getString(R.string.foo)`

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can do it that way, it probably would generally be considered "bad practice," but there are exceptions to every rule, and if your languages aren't supported by the devices, then it seems reasonable to me.

It will make it much more difficult to add new translations to the app, and depending on how you do it, potentially just difficult to work with strings in general, but it would work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database for this, but keep in mind that you will need to write A LOT of migrations for any changes

You can just add different strings files for each language
res -> right click on the 'values' folder -> new -> values resource file -> and then create new strings file with specific locale:[image]

after that in the folder with strings you will have several files:[image]

this will be a simpler and more correct approach to localize the application

Read more on https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization

Comment: He's using unsupported languages.